# Overlapping [export]/[data-liberation]/[migrate-data]/[migration] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I draw your attention to the following tags (numbers are of Open Qs):

- [data-liberation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-liberation) x42
- [migrate-data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data) x35
- [export](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) x93
- [migration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) x20

These would seem to cover virtually the same thing.

[migration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) has this usage guidance:

> Migration specifies 1) the process of moving information between different data formats or 2) the process of moving an existing user environment to a different system, for example when switching operating systems.

but seems to be a direct duplicate of [migrate-data](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate-data):

> The moving of data either between two accounts on a service or between services. Normally asked about a service's default functionality.

"Data Liberation" is a term popularized by the team that now does [google-takeout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-takeout), but it has been used on questions that aren't for Google products.

Granted, one may export data without looking to import it (like when archiving data from a service that's closing) [see also: [import](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import)], but the "export" and "migrate" tags are used fairly interchangeably.

So, how can we fix this issue?

My first suggestion is to make [data-liberation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-liberation), whose Usage guide is:

> Data liberation is the activity of retrieving a user's data from a web service.

a synonym of [export](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/export) whose Usage guide is:

> Grabbing your links, contacts and other account information and data in preparation for another service or for backing up